# MediaRecorder.start() throwing IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I have read similar threads and haven't found an answer which would solve my problem.

I am writing an app with 2 different MediaRecorders. One for noise detection and another one for recording. What I want to do is - when the first MediaRecorder detects noise levels above 4.0 (I am using Google's SoundMeter class for detection) it will initiate another MediaRecorder and start recording. If the soundlevels stay below 4.0 for 10 seconds, then stop recording and keep listening. All of this is done in an AsynTask, in an endless while(true) loop, which will be broken, only if a corresponding button is clicked.

The detection is working fine, but the IllegalStateException is thrown when start() is called on the recording MediaRecorder.

Here is the AsyncTask:

```
private class NoiseDetection extends AsyncTask {
    double currentSoundInputLevel;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        int i = 0;
        soundMeter = new SoundMeter();
        try {
            soundMeter.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
            if(isCancelled()){
                soundMeter.stop();
                if(currentlyRecording) {
                    soundRecorder.stop();
                }
                break;
            }
            currentSoundInputLevel = soundMeter.getAmplitudeEMA();
            if(!currentlyRecording && currentSoundInputLevel > 4.0){
                soundRecorder = new SoundRecorder();
                try {
                    soundRecorder.start(getFileNameString());
                    currentlyRecording = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            } else if(currentlyRecording && currentSoundInputLevel < 4.0) {
                i++;
                if(i > 10) {
                    soundRecorder.stop();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the SoundRecorder:

```
public class SoundRecorder {
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    public void start(String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception  is thrown on `mRecorder.start();`.

I think the problem lies within the idea of doing everything in this while loop, but I haven't come up with a better idea of achieving the forementioned goal.
Also, I have tried different OutputFormats and AudioEncoders without success. (reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23065021/1826152)

Another note, which could be of use, is the fact that the file is actually created in the sdcard dir.

The phone I am using for development is a Nexus 5. The permissions in android manifest are the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

---

**Update:**

Right now I have tried to remove the SoundRecorder operations from the while loop by creating a RecordingHandler. The new code for the doInBackground() is as follows:

```
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        int i = 0;
        soundMeter = new SoundMeter();
        RecordingHandler recordingHandler = null;
        try {
            soundMeter.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        while(true){
            if(isCancelled()){
                soundMeter.stop();
                if(currentlyRecording && recordingHandler != null){
                    recordingHandler.kill();
                }
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
            if(!currentlyRecording && soundMeter.getAmplitudeEMA() > 4.0){
                recordingHandler =  new RecordingHandler(deviceId);
                currentlyRecording = true;
                recordingHandler.run();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and the RecordingHandler itself is the following:

```
public class RecordingHandler implements Runnable {

    SoundRecorder soundRecorder;
    SoundMeter soundMeter;
    String deviceID;
    boolean isKilled = false;

    public RecordingHandler(String deviceID){
        this.soundRecorder = new SoundRecorder();
        this.soundMeter = new SoundMeter();
        this.deviceID = deviceID;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            soundMeter.start();
            soundRecorder.start(getFileNameString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        while(true){
            if(isKilled){
                break;
            }
            if(soundMeter.getAmplitudeEMA() < 4.0){
                i++;
                if(i > 10){
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        soundMeter.stop();
        soundRecorder.stop();
        EavesDrop.currentlyRecording = false;
    }

    public void kill(){
        this.isKilled = true;
    }

    private String getFileNameString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        return deviceID + "_" + sdf.format(new Date());
    }
}
```

Now the IllegalStateException is thrown from the Recordinghandler - on the line `soundMeter.start();`.
Considering that this soundMeter object is basically not handled in a loop anymore, should eliminate the though that the while loop was the culprit. Is there something that I am missing? **Could the problem be in having multiple MediaRecorders working at the same time?** As you can see, now it is the SoundMeter, not the SoundRecorder which is throwing the exception. Actually - whichever `start()` call I place first in the RecordingHandler, throws the same IllegalStateException.

The question might be connected to [Android: Two instances of Media recorder at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140703/android-two-instances-of-media-recorder-at-same-time), which unfortunately has no answers.

Any further help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm just curious here, Reins, but why are you using `MPEG_4` as the output format for a sound recording?

Comment: Why not? I have also tried THREE_GPP. Should I be using something else for some reason?

Comment: starting and stoping media recorder in a loop is not a good approach. If you look this diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html correctly, you'll know why

Comment: I am somewhat aware of that, but as stated in the question - I haven't come up with a better solution for achieving the goal I am after. I want the detection to keep running and record only if there is noise. Think of it like an eavesdropping device. Any suggestions on how to better achieve this are welcome. Also, how exactly might it be a problem if I create a new SoundRecorder instance, each time I start recording? @MurtazaHussain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems I cracked the problem. The problem seems to be in having multiple instances of MediaRecorder working at the same time. What I did, was that I now don't use separate classes for detection and recording, so that the recorder now does it's own detection.

At first I initiate the inital SoundMeter which listens until it gets input over level 4.0. Then I stop the initial SoundMeter and make a new SoundMeter (with different output directory), which starts recording and records until the levels have been below 4.0 for apprixamtely 10 seconds. Then the second SoundMeter is stopped and the background task can start the initial SoundMeter again.

Here is the code which solved my problem,
AsyncTask:

```
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        int i = 0;
        soundMeter = new SoundMeter();
        RecordingHandler recordingHandler = null;
        try {
            soundMeter.start("/dev/null");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        while(true){
            if(isCancelled()){
                soundMeter.stop();
                if(currentlyRecording && recordingHandler != null){
                    recordingHandler.kill();
                }
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
            if(!currentlyRecording && soundMeter.getAmplitudeEMA() > 4.0){
                soundMeter.stop();
                recordingHandler =  new RecordingHandler(deviceId);
                currentlyRecording = true;
                recordingHandler.run();
            } else if(!currentlyRecording && !soundMeter.isRunning()){
                try {
                    soundMeter.start("/dev/null");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the RecordingHandler.run():

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        soundMeter.start(getFileNameString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
    }
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        if(isKilled){
            break;
        }
        if(soundMeter.getAmplitudeEMA() < 4.0){
            i++;
            if(i > 10){
                break;
            }
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    soundMeter.stop();
    EavesDrop.currentlyRecording = false;
}
```

The documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html , under the release() method documentation, it talks about multiple instances not being suppported on some devices. So it might be a specific device related problem.